# How can I make the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn wrap to a new line if its text is too long?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, multiline, datagridviewtextboxcell

My question is simple, but I can not think of an easy solution. Lets say I have a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`. How can I make it break text into several lines if it is too long to be shown in one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new [`DataGridViewCellStyle` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.aspx) with the [`WrapMode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.wrapmode.aspx) set to "True", and assign this to the [`DefaultCellStyle` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultcellstyle.aspx) of your `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`.

For example:

```
DataGridViewCellStyle dgvCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
dgvCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

myDataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle = dgvCellStyle;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `WrapMode` of the `DefaultCellStyle` of your `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` to `true`.